# How can I get tree of relations (PrismaORM)

Tags: nest, prisma

I am trying to get tree of categories, but as far as I know in order to get relations in Prisma I have to specify them in `include` field, e.g.:

```
  const parentCategory = await this.prismaService.category.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: dto.parentId,
    },
    include: {
      childCategories: true,
    },
  });
```

Therefore I need to somehow indicate that the `childCategories` field should be output for all received subcategories and their subcategories  and so on. Or maybe there is a way to get what I want through recursive function? I am new to Prisma so please help

Category model:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIYbE.png)

Comment: There is this related GitHub Discussion: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/17746
I would recommend you to have a look at it.
You would indeed need to use a recursive function to get all nested childCategories.